# Is it legal UML in a Statemachine diagram, to give Final state a name, ex. "deleted"?

Tags: uml

Is it legal UML in a Statemachine diagram, to give Final state a name, ex. "deleted" ?

I can't do it in Astah.

/hw

Comment: you can (almost) always use notes/comments...

Comment: Clarification: I don't want to use a note, I want to name the Final state, and I am wondering if this is legal UML i.e. should I be able to do this in a UML tool that follows the specification? Or should I complain to the Astah people that their tool is out sync  with the spec ?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a name to all UML elements if needed. The tool could have implemented or not this graphical option which allows you to add a name. This is not something critical but only more codding for the tool developer :-)

Comment: Could you please refer to a paragraph in the UML specification ?

Comment: sorry mate I have no time to read the spec because prefer to be with girls on the beach :-)
btw, I don't think it is written but this is a known behavior.